# How to upgrade or rewrite newsletter _subscriber table by local sql script

Tags: magento-1.8, upgrade-script

I need to `add one field in newsletter_subscriber` table  and `create gender entity` at newsletter module in magento.I was `override controller and model`.But i am confused.

How can i add `entity in newsletter_subscriber` table.my config is below....and what should i add in my config.xml for upgrading newsletter table.

```
my config.xml
------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nine_Newsletterone>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Nine_Newsletterone>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <newsletter>
                <rewrite>
                    <subscriber>Nine_Newsletterone_Model_Subscriber</subscriber>
                   </rewrite>
            </newsletter>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsletter>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Nine_Newsletterone before="Mage_Newsletter">Nine_Newsletterone</Nine_Newsletterone>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </newsletter>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: @Amit Bera... How can I add gender coulum..in newsletter_subscriber...via script in localmodule...

Comment: i will  reply see shortly

Comment: @AmitBera ok..pls answer this

Comment: @AmitBera look my answer now its working for me....thanks for edit

Answer (score 1):

for the adding column or field in newsletter_subscriber table we have to add two  thing.

step-1.....

### change config.xml

0.1.0
        
    
    
    
        
            
                Nine_Newsletterone_Block_Adminhtml_Subscriber_grid
            
        
        
        
            
                
                    Nine_Newsletterone_Model_Subscriber

```
    <resources>

<!-- ... -->
<newsletterone_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Nine_Newsletterone</module>
        <class>Nine_Newsletterone_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
    </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
</newsletterone_setup>
<!-- ... -->
```

```
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <newsletter>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Nine_Newsletterone before="Mage_Newsletter">Nine_Newsletterone</Nine_Newsletterone>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </newsletter>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

```
create resource for your module 
app/code/local/Nine/Newsletterone/model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup

class Nine_Newsletterone_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
}

create sql installer in 
app\code\local\Nine\Newsletterone\sql\newsletterone_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.
---------------

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('newsletter/subscriber')}`
    ADD gender varchar(100);
");
$installer->endSetup();
```